# How to specify spring-data-rest version in spring-boot project?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a spring-boot project and I'm using spring data rest with it. My build.gradle file looks like this. As you can see I did everything by the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.boot) (well, apparently not everything).

What I want is to have /profile link and ability to get json-schema for all endpoints that I'm publishing. Instead I have /apls link. So I've checked  spring-data-rest manual for <2.4 version and it doesn't mention neither /profile link nor json-schema. So I've figured that I'm not using the latest version of spring-data-rest.

I've added spring boot gradle plugin and I'm not specifying version for spring-boot-data-rest dependency. I've also tried to add org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.4.0.RELEASE dependency.

But that apparently doesn't work, because I still have /alps link instead of /profile link.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE")

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'settings'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.zeromq', name: 'jeromq', version: '0.3.5'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20141113'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.skyscreamer', name: 'jsonassert', version: '1.2.3'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version:'9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.4.0.RELEASE")
    runtime group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.187'
    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

I've found that if I'm not including dependency

```
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.4.0.RELEASE")
```

Than gradle using spring-data-rest 2.2.3 or something like that.
But when I'm including that dependency it uses 2.4.0 like it should be, but then my test is failing for some reason.

My test looks like that

```
package demo;

import demo.settings.DemoApplication;
import demo.settings.processing.Channel;
import demo.settings.processing.ChannelMode;
import demo.settings.processing.ChannelsController;
import demo.settings.processing.ChannelRepository;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ChannelsController controller;
    @Autowired
    private ChannelRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void setChannels() {
        Channel exampleChannel = new Channel(ChannelMode.AUTO, 1, 1, 1, false, 0);
        controller.setChannels(0, 10, exampleChannel);
        List<Channel> allChannels = repository.findAllByOrderByBinIndexAsc();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Channel ch = allChannels.get(i);
            assertEquals(ch.getBinIndex(), i);
            assertEquals(ch.getC1(), exampleChannel.getC1(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getC2(), exampleChannel.getC2(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getManualCoefficient(), exampleChannel.getManualCoefficient(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getMode().toString(), exampleChannel.getMode().toString());
            assertEquals(ch.isExcluded(), exampleChannel.isExcluded());
        }
        exampleChannel.setC1(100);
        controller.setChannels(0, 11, exampleChannel);
        allChannels = repository.findAllByOrderByBinIndexAsc();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            Channel ch = allChannels.get(i);
            assertEquals(ch.getBinIndex(), i);
            assertEquals(ch.getC1(), exampleChannel.getC1(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getC2(), exampleChannel.getC2(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getManualCoefficient(), exampleChannel.getManualCoefficient(), 0);
            assertEquals(ch.getMode().toString(), exampleChannel.getMode().toString());
            assertEquals(ch.isExcluded(), exampleChannel.isExcluded());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="dts_stm32_settings")
interface DtsStm32SettingsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DtsStm32Settings, Long> {
}
```

Here is my Model

```
package demo.settings.data_collection.stm;



import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Created by michael on 11/09/15.
 */
@Entity
public class DtsStm32Settings extends Stm32Settings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int firstChannelDac;

    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int secondChannelDac;

    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int dil;

    @NotNull
    private CommutatorChannel commutatorChannel;


    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int firstChannelPwm;

    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int zeroChannelPwm;

    public DtsStm32Settings() {
    }

    public DtsStm32Settings(
            int firstChannelShift,
            int secondChannelShift,
            int firstChannelGain,
            int secondChannelGain,
            int firstChannelSlope,
            int secondChannelSlope,
            boolean led,
            boolean firstChannelDurationBit,
            boolean secondChannelDurationBit,
            int firstChannelDac,
            int secondChannelDac,
            int dil,
            CommutatorChannel commutatorChannel,
            int firstChannelPwm,
            int zeroChannelPwm,
            boolean pulsedPumpMode,
            int durationOn,
            int durationOff
    ) {
        super(firstChannelShift, secondChannelShift, firstChannelGain, secondChannelGain, firstChannelSlope, secondChannelSlope, led, firstChannelDurationBit, secondChannelDurationBit);
        this.firstChannelDac = firstChannelDac;
        this.secondChannelDac = secondChannelDac;
        this.dil = dil;
        this.commutatorChannel = commutatorChannel;
        this.firstChannelPwm = firstChannelPwm;
        this.zeroChannelPwm = zeroChannelPwm;
        this.pulsedPumpMode = pulsedPumpMode;
        this.durationOn = durationOn;
        this.durationOff = durationOff;
    }

    @NotNull
    private boolean pulsedPumpMode;

    @NotNull @Min(value=1) @Max(value=65535)
    private int durationOn;

    @NotNull @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    private int durationOff;

    public int getFirstChannelPwm() {
        return firstChannelPwm;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelPwm(int firstChannelPwm) {
        this.firstChannelPwm = firstChannelPwm;
    }

    public int getZeroChannelPwm() {
        return zeroChannelPwm;
    }

    public void setZeroChannelPwm(int zeroChannelPwm) {
        this.zeroChannelPwm = zeroChannelPwm;
    }

    public int getFirstChannelDac() {
        return firstChannelDac;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelDac(int firstChannelDac) {
        this.firstChannelDac = firstChannelDac;
    }

    public int getSecondChannelDac() {
        return secondChannelDac;
    }

    public void setSecondChannelDac(int secondChannelDac) {
        this.secondChannelDac = secondChannelDac;
    }

    public int getDil() {
        return dil;
    }

    public void setDil(int dil) {
        this.dil = dil;
    }

    public CommutatorChannel getCommutatorChannel() {
        return commutatorChannel;
    }

    public void setCommutatorChannel(CommutatorChannel commutatorChannel) {
        this.commutatorChannel = commutatorChannel;
    }

    public boolean isPulsedPumpMode() {
        return pulsedPumpMode;
    }

    public void setPulsedPumpMode(boolean pulsedPumpMode) {
        this.pulsedPumpMode = pulsedPumpMode;
    }

    public int getDurationOn() {
        return durationOn;
    }

    public void setDurationOn(int durationOn) {
        this.durationOn = durationOn;
    }

    public int getDurationOff() {
        return durationOff;
    }

    public void setDurationOff(int durationOff) {
        this.durationOff = durationOff;
    }
}


package demo.settings.data_collection.stm;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Created by michael on 11/09/15.
 */

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(DtsStm32Settings.class)})
abstract class Stm32Settings {

    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int firstChannelShift;
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int secondChannelShift;
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int firstChannelGain;
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int secondChannelGain;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int firstChannelSlope;
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=0) @Max(value=65535)
    protected int secondChannelSlope;
    @NotNull
    protected boolean led;
    @NotNull
    protected boolean firstChannelDurationBit;
    @NotNull
    protected boolean secondChannelDurationBit;

    protected Stm32Settings() {
    }


    public int getFirstChannelShift() {
        return firstChannelShift;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelShift(int firstChannelShift) {
        this.firstChannelShift = firstChannelShift;
    }

    public int getSecondChannelShift() {
        return secondChannelShift;
    }

    public void setSecondChannelShift(int secondChannelShift) {
        this.secondChannelShift = secondChannelShift;
    }

    public int getFirstChannelGain() {
        return firstChannelGain;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelGain(int firstChannelGain) {
        this.firstChannelGain = firstChannelGain;
    }

    public int getSecondChannelGain() {
        return secondChannelGain;
    }

    public void setSecondChannelGain(int secondChannelGain) {
        this.secondChannelGain = secondChannelGain;
    }

    public int getFirstChannelSlope() {
        return firstChannelSlope;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelSlope(int firstChannelSlope) {
        this.firstChannelSlope = firstChannelSlope;
    }

    public int getSecondChannelSlope() {
        return secondChannelSlope;
    }

    public void setSecondChannelSlope(int secondChannelSlope) {
        this.secondChannelSlope = secondChannelSlope;
    }

    public boolean isLed() {
        return led;
    }

    public void setLed(boolean led) {
        this.led = led;
    }

    public boolean isFirstChannelDurationBit() {
        return firstChannelDurationBit;
    }

    public void setFirstChannelDurationBit(boolean firstChannelDurationBit) {
        this.firstChannelDurationBit = firstChannelDurationBit;
    }

    public boolean isSecondChannelDurationBit() {
        return secondChannelDurationBit;
    }

    public void setSecondChannelDurationBit(boolean secondChannelDurationBit) {
        this.secondChannelDurationBit = secondChannelDurationBit;
    }

    public Stm32Settings(
            int firstChannelShift,
            int secondChannelShift,
            int firstChannelGain,
            int secondChannelGain,
            int firstChannelSlope,
            int secondChannelSlope,
            boolean led,
            boolean firstChannelDurationBit,
            boolean secondChannelDurationBit
    ) {
        setFirstChannelShift(firstChannelShift);
        setSecondChannelShift(secondChannelShift);
        setFirstChannelGain(firstChannelGain);
        setSecondChannelGain(secondChannelGain);
        setFirstChannelSlope(firstChannelSlope);
        setSecondChannelSlope(secondChannelSlope);
        setLed(led);
        setFirstChannelDurationBit(firstChannelDurationBit);
        setSecondChannelDurationBit(secondChannelDurationBit);
    }
}
```

And here is error which tells me about nothing

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stm32Controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private demo.settings.data_collection.stm.DtsStm32SettingsRepository demo.settings.data_collection.stm.Stm32Controller.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dtsStm32SettingsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:104)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private demo.settings.data_collection.stm.DtsStm32SettingsRepository demo.settings.data_collection.stm.Stm32Controller.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dtsStm32SettingsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dtsStm32SettingsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: Explicitly setting the version, as you have done, should be sufficient to get 2.4.0.RELEASE. You can use `./gradlew dependencies` to check.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I had error in dependencies. I've written 'compole' instead of 'compile'. I've fix this and now my test are failing. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying Spring Data *release train* instead:

```
dependencyManagement {
   imports {
     ...
       mavenBom "org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Gosling-RELEASE"
   }
}
```

Then just compile the spring-data starters you need without specifying the version!

Comment: thanks, that works. I would add that there is need to install spring-dependency-management plugin for grade to do that.